# AWS SDK in Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, windows-10

I'm attempting to use the AWS SDK in a Windows 10 Universal App I'm developing and when trying to import the 'AWSSDK.Core.dll' and 'AWSSDK.S3.dll' in order to use S3 functionality I receive the following error:

```
A reference to '..\AWSSDK.Core.dll' could not be added. The project targets
'.NETCore' while the file reference targets '.NETFramework'. This is not a
supported scenario.
```

Is there something I'm missing that I need to do in order to make use of the SDK or are they just incompatible at this moment in time?

Comment: Check out this blog post: http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx1F10SP4VKWXGX/Supporting-Windows-Phone-8-1

Comment: @CoryCharlton Hey Cory, I had stumbled on your link before posting my question which is why I had asked since it seemed to be possible. The resolution seems to be to simply install the AWSSDK through NuGet. I just found an explanation/readme file in the installation folder specifying this. I'll post my answer once the timer lets me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible but the available resources are a little misleading. The results found on the AWS Blog(http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx1F10SP4VKWXGX/Supporting-Windows-Phone-8-1) state that it is available in the MSI installer but this is in fact **NOT** the case as of this post. The only way I was able to access the AWSSDK services is through installing the AWSSDK through the Visual Studio NuGet console. The console in VS2015 Professional is located in the Tools menu. The command is simply:

```
Install-Package AWSSDK
```